# Passing values from Capistrano deploy.rb file to app

Tags: ruby, configuration, sinatra, capistrano

In my Capistrano's deploy.rb file, I set up different environments such as server names, ports, etc.  I also require the users to send a callback to another server, also defined in the deploy.rb. How do I cleanly pass this value to my app?

Something to this effect:

config/deploy.rb:

```
set :callback_url, "http://somecallbackurl.com:12345/bla"
```

app/controllers/myapp.rb:

```
def get_callback_url
   ???
end
```

I'm using Sinatra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, and that is to use the environment variables.

Set it from deploy.rb

```
run "export CALLBACK_URL=#{callback_url}"
```

From app:

```
def get_callback_url
    ENV['CALLBACK_URL']
end
```

I wouldn't say it's the cleanest solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably recommend using a shared YAML file to store this kind of configuration, and loading it separately. For example, have a file named something like `config/settings.yml`, containing something like:

```
:callback_url: "http://somecallbackurl.com:12345/bla"
```

In `config/deploy.rb`, you could have:

```
settings = YAML.load_file('config/settings.yml')
set :callback_url, settings[:callback_url]
```

And in `config/initializers/settings.rb`, you could have:

```
settings = YAML.load_file('config/settings.yml')
CALLBACK_URL = settings[:callback_url]
```

Finally, in `app/controllers/myapp.rb`, you would do:

```
def get_callback_url
   CALLBACK_URL
end
```

Using a shared YAML file is just the first thing I thought of. Another approach would be defining some constants in a ruby file, and requiring that file both in an initializer, and in `deploy.rb`. The basic idea is that you don't really want your app to depend on your capistrano environment, so you should find a way to separate the shared configuration.

Comment: Hm..It is getting a bit complicated if I use another file. `callback_url` will change on different environments. Production might say `prod.callbackurl.com` while dev/qa environments are pointing to somewhere else. I'm using capistrano-ext to manage different stages.